# PHP MySQL Update query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website that has an update query. Example.

```
Table name -> myTable
Table Content -> id(AI)
                 name  --> myName
                 age   --> 13
                 image --> (no values)
                 birthdate  --> (no values)
```

I only put values in **name** and **age**. In **image** and **birthdate**, I haven't put anything.
If I edit it and update it and I don't put anything in **name** and in **age**, I only put values in **image** and in **birthdate**. The output is like this. **(This ouput I wanted)**

```
Table name -> myTable
Table Content -> id(AI)
                 name  --> myName
                 age   --> 13
                 image --> myImage.jpg
                 birthdate  --> Feb. 31, 2010
```

This is my code:

```
<?php
  //mysql connect...
  //mysql select database...
$sql = "UPDATE myTable SET name = '".$name."', age = '".$age."', image = '".$image."', birthdate"'$birthdate.."' WHERE id = $id";
mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

I used this code but the output is:

```
Table name -> myTable
Table Content -> id(AI)
                 name  --> (no values)
                 age   --> (no values)
                 image --> myImage.jpg
                 birthdate  --> Feb. 31, 2010
```

**Feel free to ask if you don't understand my question** 
**Thank you**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UPDATE` leaves columns as they were if you don't include new values in your `UPDATE` statement.

So you may need to build up the `$sql` variable with some conditional code that examines what the user entered, and then only include a column if the user gave a value for it.

```
<?php

$columns = array("name", "age", "image", "birthdate");
$set = array();
foreach ($columns as $col) {
    if (isset($_GET[$col])) {
      $set[] = "$col = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[$col]) . "'";
    }
}
$sql = "UPDATE myTable "
if ($set) {
    $sql .= " SET " . implode(",", $set);
}
$sql .= " WHERE id = " . (int) $id;
```

Comment: It might be better to use `!empty($_GET[$col])` instead of `isset`. If the form has fixed inputs (e.g.: inputs are not added or disabled dynamically), then empty inputs would be treated as if a new value was provided.

Answer (score 2):

you have an error in your code--

```
$sql = "UPDATE myTable SET name = '".$name."', age = '".$age."', image = '".$image."', birthdate"'$birthdate.."' WHERE id = $id"
```

should read:

```
$sql = "UPDATE myTable SET name = '".$name."', age = '".$age."', image = '".$image."', birthdate = '".$birthdate."' WHERE id = $id"
```

but that's probably just a typo. Are you sure that the variables are getting set correctly? Try echoing out all the vars to make sure. Also, check that the columns have no default data definition.

Comment: Beat me to it: birthdate"'$birthdate.."'

Comment: Thank you. ^^. I forgot the equal sign.

Answer (score 1):

Just have two separate queries:

```
// update name and age
$sql = "UPDATE myTable SET name = '$name', age = '$age' WHERE id = '$id'";

// Update image and birthday
$sql = "UPDATE myTable SET image = '$image', birthdate = '$birthdate' WHERE id = '$id'";
```

Also, you can just put all of the variables inside the string since it's double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change a field, don't include it in the update query.

Answer (score 0):

Personally i think that quires like this are not that reliable, Especially when it comes down to typecasting etc.

I recommend you try and implement PDO or something.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Othewise, the error is `birthdate'".$birthdate."'` witch needs to be `birthdate = '".$birthdate."'`